# Android Application Crash when calling intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I face a problem in android application. When I call Intent with a button the window disappear. Here is my code:

```
public void btn_open_click(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add_User.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and here is Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.antiatlasdev.myapplication">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="Add_User"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls share your logcat output with the error message

Comment: `Add_User.class` did you try to remove the '.class' ?

Comment: If your class is in the package `com.example.antiatlasdev.myapplication` you can use either the notation `android:name="com.example.antiatlasdev.myapplication.Add_User"` or `android:name=".Add_User"`

Comment: android:name=".Add_User" add . before Add_User if this activity is in same package as MainActivity

Comment: i did that and still having the same problem

Comment: Can you please specify what error are you getting?

Comment: Please try to print a log or show a toast on your button click to be sure about your button click is performing fine. Then have some look at your Add_User class. You can also share your Add_User class code here.

Comment: i am new to android studio how print log or how to print errors in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.antiatlasdev.myapplication.Add_User"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"</activity>
```

use this

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't use the correct class name for the activity. You're using inccorrect class name:

```
<activity android:name="Add_User"  
   android:label="@string/app_name">
</ activity>
```

It should be using `.Add_User` instead of `Add_User`. You need to add the `.` to tell that your activity name is relative to your package name. Or you can also using the complete package name and the class activity name. Something like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.yourpackagename.Add_User" 
   android:label="@string/app_name"> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`name`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm) attribute

> should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package name specified in the  element.

So, if the `Add_User` class in in the `com.example.antiatlasdev.myapplication` package you can code as:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Add_User"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

while if `Add_User` is in another package, for example in the `com.example.antiatlasdev.anotherPackage` package, then you will have to specify it like:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.antiatlasdev.anotherPackage.Add_User"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```